# Import multiple excels using gdata in R - add filenamevar

Tags: r, excel, gdata, lapply

Im trying to merge multiple excel 2013 files and write it into a new csv file.
For whatever reason I cant load package xlsx on RStudio so I use gdata package instead;
I the script below works however I want to add file name variables as a new column. I dont know how to achieve this. Please can someone advice me?

setwd(MY_DIRECTORY)
    x <- file_path_sans_ext(filelist)
    filelist <- list.files(pattern = "*\.xlsx$")

```
files <- lapply(filelist, read.xls, header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
files <- lapply(files, function(x) x[])
df <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all=T), files)

write.csv(new, "mynewfile.csv")
```

Thank you
Peddie

Comment: have you tried the [relatively new] readxl package? if you are on linux you can use ssconvert if you have installed gnumeric.

Comment: I haven't actually but the big I would love to achieve most is pasting the file name as a new column - could you please advice how I can do this? I'm very new to R

Comment: ?basename is what you are looking for.

Comment: To add to my question,  for example I have excel col1, col2, col3 in all files and I want to paste each file name as col4. The script I posted above seem to merge everything in perfectly except I cant paste the filename in as col4 :( havent succeeded yet. Anyone can advice please?